# : kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property manager has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I am developing news and I am getting following nullpointexception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari/yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.WelcomeActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property manager has not been initialized
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2976)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
 at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property manager has not been initialized
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.kt:26)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
 ... 11 more
```

below my WelcomeActivity.kt class

```
class WelcomeActivity : AppIntro() {


    private  lateinit  var manager: PreferencesManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Make sure you don't call setContentView!

        if (manager.isFirstRun()) {
            showIntroSlides()
        } else {
            goToMain()
        }
    }

        // Call addSlide passing your Fragments.

        // You can use AppIntroFragment to use a pre-built fragment

       private fun showIntroSlides() {
           manager.setFirstRun()
           addSlide(
                AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
                    title = "Welcome to the NewsApp",
                    description = "NewsApp give your information about life news around the world",
                    imageDrawable = R.drawable.news,
                    backgroundDrawable = R.drawable.news_slider,
                    titleColor = Color.YELLOW,
                    descriptionColor = Color.RED,
                    backgroundColor = Color.BLUE,
                    titleTypefaceFontRes = R.font.opensans_light,
                    descriptionTypefaceFontRes = R.font.opensans_regular
                )
            )
            addSlide(
                AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
                    title = "...Let's get started!",
                    description = "This is the last slide, I won't annoy you more :)"
                )
            )
        }

    private fun goToMain() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }

    override fun onSkipPressed(currentFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment)
      goToMain()


    }

    override fun onDonePressed(currentFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onDonePressed(currentFragment)
        goToMain()
    }
    override fun onSlideChanged(oldFragment: Fragment?, newFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onSlideChanged(oldFragment, newFragment)
        Log.d("Hello", "Changed")
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is the causing null pointer exception even I have tried initialize manager following way

```
private var manager: PreferencesManager? = null
```

but it did not solve my problem
I want to know where I am making mistake what I have to do avoid nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple by looking into logs. Your `manager` is not initialized before using. Look at onCreate

```
    private  lateinit  var manager: PreferencesManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Make sure you don't call setContentView!

        // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< INITIALISE manager HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

        if (manager.isFirstRun()) { <<<<<<<< HERE you are using an uninitilised manager
            showIntroSlides()
        } else {
            goToMain()
        }
    }
```

Initialise `manager` before `if (manager.isFirstRun()) {` in `onCreate()`

Comment: okay I understand here I am making nullpointer exception what I have to do in order to avoid

Comment: @sashabeliy See updates of my answer. You need to initialize manager. lateinit does not create objects.

Comment: var manager: PreferencesManager? = null
        // Make sure you don't call setContentView!
        if (manager?.isFirstRun()!!) {
            showIntroSlides()
        } else {
            goToMain()
        }
    } like this but app still crashes

Comment: Do you know how to create an object of PreferencesManager?

Comment: if I am doing as you said in other method I cant call manager you suggesting not working at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214233/discussion-between-sashabeliy-and-pankaj-kumar).